# Connect 2 or more markers in the leaflet with coordinates from GeoJSON

Tags: leaflet, point, geojson, marker, polyline

I have to draw a line between 2 or more points (markers). The coordinates are in a GeoJSON file (attached). I tried to make an assignment for the properties: these are "node worker" a point of "Master" and the other and "knot workers" with connecting the "master".
but has not worked and that's why I need your help ... How can I implement it?

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [
{"type": "Feature","properties": {"id":"1","name":"Berlin","wert":"","pc":"master"},"geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [13.523563700000068,52.4909447]}},
{"type": "Feature","properties": {"id":"2","name":"Hamburg","wert":"0","pc":"wn"},"geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [9.99368179999999,53.5510846]}},
{"type": "Feature","properties": {"id":"3","name":"München","wert":"128","pc":"wn"},"geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [11.581980599999952,48.1351253]}},
{"type": "Feature","properties": {"id":"4","name":"Frankfurt am Main","wert":"-128","pc":"wn"},"geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [8.682126700000026,50.1109221]}}
]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `LineString` features to your featurecollection: http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id3 Leaflet's `L.GeoJSON` layer will convert them to Polylines: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polyline

If changing your GeoJSON file isn't an option. You could write logic which loops over the features in your layer, then separate the master and clients and then draw polylines between them.

After comment:

You've supplied a GeoJSON with the coordinates of the master PC. 13.523563700000068,52.4909447 You want to connect it via Polyline with a client PC. I'll pick the coordinates of the first one: 9.99368179999999,53.5510846. So you add another feature to your GeoJSON collection, a polyline:

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
            [13.523563700000068,52.4909447], // Master PC coordinates
            [9.99368179999999,53.5510846] // WN1 Coordinates
        ]
    },
    "properties": {
        "label": "From Master to First client"
    }
}
```

And you're gold. Here's a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ndasgy?p=preview

Comment: thank you!
but I do not quite understand, because leaflet is new for me.
can you please explain this with an example?

Comment: thank you! but I meant that the line is automatically drawn between the marker and not the coordinates is entered by hand, that's no problem ...
I want the takes the line, the coordinates (Master PC - beginning, end WN) from the file.

Comment: I also have first done so ... but now I need an automatic storage.

Comment: `... {"type": "Feature","properties": {"id":"5","verbindung":"Berlin-Hamburg","wert":"0"},"geometry": {"type": "LineString","coordinates": [[13.523563700000068,52.4909447 ],[9.99368179999999,53.5510846]]}},

 {"type": "Feature","properties": {"id":"7","verbindung":"Berlin-Frankfurt am Main","wert":"256"},"geometry": {"type": "LineString","coordinates": [[13.523563700000068,52.4909447 ],[8.682126700000026,50.1109221]]}}]}`